# Why does this work for my dictionary snippet?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

```
{1:2,3:{4,5}}
```

Why does this work? I thought I ran a typo but it threw a valid output!

Is {4,5} a nested dictionary or something akin to a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have a dictionary which contains a set. Dictionary are key-value paired objects whose value can be anything, integers, lists, sets, dataframes, dictionaries, etc...

In this particular case we can see this by performing a few prints with `type`:

```
A = {1:2,3:{4,5}}
print(A, " is of type " , type(A))
print(A[1], "is of type " , type(A[1]))
print(A[3], "is of type " , type(A[3]))
```

Which correctly outputs:

```
{1: 2, 3: {4, 5}}  is of type  <class 'dict'>
2 is of type  <class 'int'>
{4, 5} is of type  <class 'set'>
```

This would be output if `A = {1:2,3:{4,4}}`

```
{4} is of type  <class 'set'>
```

Because `set` contain unique elements, hence repetitions get eliminated. Here you can find more information regarding [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Comment: this helps, what if I tried {4,4} instead of 4,5 though?

Comment: You'd have {4}.

Comment: As Denis stated, I edited my answer to include this scenario @Pi_die_die

Comment: and I added the  set tag to my question for future referers

Answer (score 2):

It's a `set`

```
>>> {4, 5}
{4, 5}
>>> s = {4, 5}
>>> s
{4, 5}
>>> type(s)
<class 'set'>
```

You can store any valid python object as a value in a dictionary.
Hence, `{1:2,3:{4,5}}` is a valid dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set). Sets behave sort of like dictionaries without keys (or without values). You can put anything you want as a dictionary value (including another dictionary). Dictionary keys have to be hashable, though.

Answer (score 1):

{4, 5} is a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). It is a sorted list-like container with unique items, so it's similar to a dictionary.